# Automate zooming/panning to selected feature(s) in QGIS without manual clicks

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, features, zoom

I'm wondering if there's a functionality or a button in **QGIS** that allows for **automatic zooming and panning** to the currently selected feature. Instead of manually clicking zoom/pan buttons each time, is there a way to streamline this process through a button or some automation?

**At present**, there are two buttons available in the attribute table that allow for **manual** zooming and panning:

[image: snippet]

Comment: Standard shortcuts are "ctrl+p" and "ctrl+j", as a longer mouseover reveals. Shortcuts may be modified to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you @Erik, I was wondering if I can automate the zooming, without manually click the shortcut "ctrl+p" and "ctrl+j", such as JGH suggested. But the shortcuts are useful, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This option is available in `form view`

[image]

Comment: Thats what I searched for. I did not know that it hides in the form view ;) Thank you!

Comment: is there a way to automatically zoom to the current feature in attribute view?

Answer (score 5):

Quickest option: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to Zoom to the selected feature(s).

Comment: Thank you @Babel, I was wondering if I can automate the zooming, without manually click the shortcut "ctrl+j", such as JGH suggested. But the shortcuts are useful, though.

Answer (score 3):

In the `Map Navigation Toolbar`, there is a <kbd>**Zoom to Selection**</kbd> icon. If the toolbar is missing, acitvate in in Menu <kbd>Views</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbars</kbd>.

[image]

If the icon is not present in the toolbar, activate it in Menu <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Interface Customiuaiton</kbd>, then filter for `zoom` and check the box next to `mActionZoomToSelected`:

[image]